# how to check the socket type is in socket.SOCK_STREAM or socket.SOCK_DGRAM in python3

Tags: python, sockets

Here is the python2 code:

```
if type not in (socket.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SOCK_DGRAM):
    msg = "Socket type must be stream or datagram, not {!r}"
    raise ValueError(msg.format(type))
```

Now in python3 it is not working correctly and in socket official doc I have seen:

> the The `AF_*` and `SOCK_*` constants are now AddressFamily and SocketKind 
>   IntEnum collections.

but i do not understand it .

so how can i check the socket type is in `socket.SOCK_STREAM` or `socket.SOCK_DGRAM` in python3 ?

Comment: "*In python3 it can not work correctly*" -- what error message or incorrect behavior do you see in Python3?

Comment: Please provide a short, **complete** program that demonstrates the problem. When I insert your code into a [complete program](http://ideone.com/gFNOEO), it works flawlessly for me in either Python2 or Python3.

Comment: i have made a pull request in github , you can see in  [https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/pull/31](https://github.com/Anorov/PySocks/pull/31)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ ipython3

In [1]: import socket

In [4]: list(socket.SocketKind)

Out[4]:

[<SocketKind.SOCK_RAW: 3>,
 <SocketKind.SOCK_SEQPACKET: 5>,
 <SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM: 1>,
 <SocketKind.SOCK_RDM: 4>,
 <SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM: 2>]
```

so i guess it does the trick :

```
if type not in (socket.SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, socket.SocketKind.SOCK_DGRAM)
```

Comment: `>>> import socket`
`>>> socket.SOCK_STREAM == socket.SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM`
`True`  YES   thanks.